# How to perform pca analysis with pandas

Tags: python, pca, implementation

Here is my dataset:

```
    A1        A2   A3  Class
3    1  0.440671  2.3      1
14   1  0.868410  1.5      1
29   1  0.587487  2.6      1
34   1  0.652936  3.0      1
45   1  0.953230  3.0      1
..  ..       ...  ...    ...
92   2  0.775842  2.3      2
95   2  0.844920  2.2      2
96   2  0.428071  2.2      2
97   2  0.356044  2.2      3
99   2  0.815400  2.2      3
```

My goal is to apply principal component analysis on the dataset, convert it into a new
dataset, and save the new dataset. I have created an example program that does this for three vectors:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

A = [45,37,42,35,39]
B = [38,31,26,28,33]
C = [10,15,17,21,12]

dataset = np.array(A,B,C)

A_norm = A/np.linalg.norm(A)
B_norm = B/np.linalg.norm(B)
C_norm = C/np.linalg.norm(C)

data = np.array([A_norm,B_norm,C_norm])

# determine covariance
covMatrix = np.cov(data,bias=True)
print (covMatrix)

# compute eigen vactors and eigenvalues
w, v = LA.eig(covMatrix)
print("eigen vectors")
print(v)

print("eigen values")
print(w)

varianceV = np.empty(3)

# calculate variances
varianceV[0] = w[0]/(w[0]+w[1]+w[2])
varianceV[1] = w[1]/(w[0]+w[1]+w[2])
varianceV[2] = w[2]/(w[0]+w[1]+w[2])


print(f' variance of v1 : {varianceV[0]}')
print(f' variance of v2 : {varianceV[1]}')
print(f' variance of v3 : {varianceV[2]}')

# calculate feature vector
v_initial = 0
featureVector = np.empty(3)
for i in range(0,3):
    if varianceV[i] > v_initial:
        featureVector = v[i]

print(f'feature vector: {featureVector}')
resolved_dataset = np.concatenate(featureVector,dataset)
print(f'dataset = {resolved_dataset}')
```

I am trying to use the example above to replace the method

```
def pca(s):
    # Normalize each s
    s_normalized=(s - s.mean()) / s.std()
    pca = PCA(n_components=s.shape[1])
    pca.fit(s_normalized)

    # build the covariance matrix of the s.

    # rank eigenvectors in descending order of their eigenvalues
    # and keep the the significant eigenvectors

    # build the feature vector our of the selected eigenvectors
    
    # Reformat and view results
    loadings = pd.DataFrame(pca.components_.T,
    columns=['PC%s' % _ for _ in range(len(s_normalized.columns))],
    index=s.columns)
    print(loadings)

    plot.plot(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
    plot.ylabel('Explained Variance')
    plot.xlabel('Components')
    plot.show()

    # TODO: return transformed data.
    s = pca.transform(s_normalized)
    return s
```

Minimal reproducible example

data

```
A1,A2,A3,Class
2,0.4631338,1.5,3
8,0.7460648,3.0,3
6,0.264391038,2.5,2
5,0.4406713,2.3,1
2,0.410438159,1.5,3
2,0.302901816,1.5,2
6,0.275869396,2.5,3
8,0.084782428,3.0,3
2,0.53226533,1.5,2
8,0.070034818,2.9,1
2,0.668631847,1.5,2
2,0.215622639,1.5,2
2,0.148916231,1.5,3
2,0.51335434,1.5,3
```

program

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import count
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
from math import ceil, floor, log2
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

def print_full(x):
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', len(x))
    print(x)
    pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')

def main():
    s = pd.read_csv('A1-dm.csv')
    s = pca(s)


def pca(s):
    # Normalize each s
    s_normalized=(s - s.mean()) / s.std()
    pca = PCA(n_components=s.shape[1])
    pca.fit(s_normalized)

    # build the covariance matrix of the s.

    # rank eigenvectors in descending order of their eigenvalues
    # and keep the the significant eigenvectors

    # build the feature vector our of the selected eigenvectors
    
    # Reformat and view results
    loadings = pd.DataFrame(pca.components_.T,
    columns=['PC%s' % _ for _ in range(len(s_normalized.columns))],
    index=s.columns)
    print(loadings)

    plot.plot(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
    plot.ylabel('Explained Variance')
    plot.xlabel('Components')
    plot.show()

    # TODO: return transformed data.
    s = pca.transform(s_normalized)
    return s
    
main()
```

The problem that I am facing is trying to resolve the last step where I multiply the dataset by the feature vector.